# How to open/load a vsix file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mvvm-light, vsix

I am trying to install MvvmLight Toolkit to my Visual Studio. I have a VSIX file which looks as follows -

[image]

When I try to open it (by double clicking), it asks me to choose a program to open with...

Like this..

[image]

I dont know what to do here.

Can somebody tell me how I can install MvvmLight using vsix file? I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the `Visual Studio Version Selector` option in the `open with...` window and it worked.

I should have tried that option before asking.

Comment: I downloaded the `VSIX` file and installed it. How do I access it from Visual Studio?